# Robot is not moving to Goal location. Moving in straight direction only

Tags: gazebo, simulation, diff-drive-controller

I have simulated the robot with libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so plugin. I have written python script to move robot to goal location. But When I am running this go_to_goal.py, the robot is moving in straight direction only (not taking any angular velocity to reach goal). It is not moving towards the goal.

I have attached my go_to_goal.py file and videos of issues and urdf file for reference. What will be solution for this?

Video of issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ltd_PpBYZWydsiYq8Mk7Mg4FgcjrchCy/view?usp=drive_link

go_to_goal.py file

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist, Point
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
import math
import sys

class RobotGoToGoal(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('goal_movement_node')
        self.velocity_pub_ = self.create_publisher(Twist, '/cmd_vel', 10)
        self.pose_sub_ = self.create_subscription(Odometry, '/odom', self.poseCallback, 10)
        timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.go_to_goal_function)

        self.robot_pose = Point()
        self.goal_pose = Point()
        self.angle_to_goal_ = 0.0
        self.distance_to_goal_ = 0.0
               
    def poseCallback(self, data):
        # Reading the odometry message from /odom topic and printed on console
        self.robot_pose.x = data.pose.pose.position.x
        self.robot_pose.y = data.pose.pose.position.y

        quaternion = data.pose.pose.orientation
        (roll, pitch, yaw) = self.euler_from_quaternion(quaternion.x, quaternion.y, quaternion.z, quaternion.w)
        self.robot_pose.z = yaw
        
        
    def go_to_goal_function(self):
        self.goal_pose.x = float(sys.argv[1])
        self.goal_pose.y = float(sys.argv[2])
        self.angle_offset = float(sys.argv[3])

        self.distance_to_goal_ = math.sqrt(pow( (self.goal_pose.x - self.robot_pose.x), 2) + pow (( self.goal_pose.y - self.robot_pose.y), 2))
        self.angle_to_goal_ = math.atan2(self.goal_pose.y - self.robot_pose.y, self.goal_pose.x - self.robot_pose.x) + self.angle_offset

        self.angle_to_turn = self.angle_to_goal_ - self.robot_pose.z

        vel_msg = Twist()

        if abs (self.angle_to_turn ) > 0.1:
            vel_msg.linear.x = 0.0
            vel_msg.angular.z = self.angle_to_turn
            
        else:
            vel_msg.linear.x = self.distance_to_goal_

        self.velocity_pub_.publish(vel_msg)

        self.get_logger().info("DTG: %f ATT: %f" %(self.distance_to_goal_, self.angle_to_turn))

    # Function to convert quaternion angles coming from /odom topic to euler angles
    def euler_from_quaternion(self, x, y, z, w):
        t0 = +2.0 * (w * x + y * z)
        t1 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (x * x + y * y)
        roll_x = math.atan2(t0, t1)

        t2 = +2.0 * (w * y - z * x)
        t2 = +1.0 if t2 > +1.0 else t2
        t2 = -1.0 if t2 < -1.0 else t2
        pitch_y = math.asin(t2)

        t3 = +2.0 * (w * z + x * y)
        t4 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (y * y + z * z)
        yaw_z = math.atan2(t3, t4)

        return roll_x, pitch_y, yaw_z
  
def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    goal_movement_node = RobotGoToGoal()

    rclpy.spin(goal_movement_node)
    goal_movement_node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

urdf file:

```
<!-- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
This URDF was automatically created by SolidWorks to URDF Exporter! Originally created by Stephen Brawner (brawner@gmail.com) 
     Commit Version: 1.6.0-4-g7f85cfe  Build Version: 1.6.7995.38578
     For more information, please see http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter -->

<robot name="maze_bot" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <link name="base_footprint"/>
  <link
    name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.00707441861578902 1.50100156470767E-08 0.0165884290645345"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0572931263149315" />
      <inertia
        ixx="9.76622308524917E-06"
        ixy="2.66695153277329E-12"
        ixz="5.31595893580279E-06"
        iyy="3.95339677938339E-05"
        iyz="-2.55649753682889E-12"
        izz="3.50254141598992E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://maze_bot/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0 1 0 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://maze_bot/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <contact_coefficients mu="0" kp="1000.0" kd="1.0"/>
    </collision>
  </link>

<joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
   <parent link="base_footprint"/>
   <child link="base_link"/>
   <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.005"/>
 </joint>

  <link
    name="wheel_left">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-6.245E-17 -2.0817E-17 -0.005"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.007092" />
      <inertia
        ixx="8.9183E-07"
        ixy="1.2996E-22"
        ixz="6.5819E-24"
        iyy="8.9183E-07"
        iyz="1.1132E-23"
        izz="1.6849E-06" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://maze_bot/meshes/wheel_left.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0 0 0.8 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://maze_bot/meshes/wheel_left.STL" />
      </geometry>
      
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="left_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.02236 0.0225 0.014121"
      rpy="-1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel_left" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel_right">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-6.93889390390723E-17 3.46944695195361E-17 0.00499999999999998"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0070920053812245" />
      <inertia
        ixx="8.91826194551389E-07"
        ixy="3.12777669121614E-24"
        ixz="-2.59177095819046E-23"
        iyy="8.91826194551389E-07"
        iyz="-3.47806816020164E-25"
        izz="1.68487825669228E-06" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://maze_bot/meshes/wheel_right.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0 0 0.8 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://maze_bot/meshes/wheel_right.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <contact_coefficients mu="0" kp="1000.0" kd="1.0"/>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="right_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.02236 -0.0225 0.014121"
      rpy="-1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel_right" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="front_caster">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 -1.3878E-17 -0.0020065"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.00032085" />
      <inertia
        ixx="2.3826E-09"
        ixy="1.1065E-25"
        ixz="5.0079E-25"
        iyy="2.3826E-09"
        iyz="-9.9843E-26"
        izz="3.6744E-09" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://maze_bot/meshes/front_caster.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://maze_bot/meshes/front_caster.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <contact_coefficients mu="0" kp="1000.0" kd="1.0"/>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="front_caster_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0.0276774999770471 0 -0.003"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="front_caster" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>

  <!-- ROS 2 Control -->
  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so" name="gazebo_base_controller">
      <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
      <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
      <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
      <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
      <update_rate>15.0</update_rate>
      <left_joint>left_joint</left_joint>
      <right_joint>right_joint</right_joint>
      <wheel_separation>0.8</wheel_separation>
      <wheel_diameter>0.3</wheel_diameter>
      <max_wheel_acceleration>0.7</max_wheel_acceleration>
      <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>

    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="front_caster">
    <material>Gazebo/White</material>
  </gazebo>
  
  <gazebo reference="wheel_right">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="wheel_left">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
  </gazebo> 

</robot>
```